Meta tag return error in next js 14.1.3 app router
I'm using Next.js 14 with the app router, and I've written the above code to use meta tags.
It seems like you're encountering a 418 error code while using the Facebook meta tag debugging page.
working in slack,ms teams but  not working in facebook , rankmath like this
fail image
Below is my code, please find the problem.
this is my code


export const metadata: Metadata = {
  title: {
    template: " %s - EXAMPLE",
    default: "EXAMPLE"
  },
  icons: {
    icon: fa.src
  },
  metadataBase: new URL('https://EXAMPLE.COM/'),
  description: EXAMPLE",
  authors: {
    name: "EXAMPLE", url: "https://EXAMPLE.com/"
  },
  openGraph: {
    images: [{ url: METAIMAGE.src }],
    type: "website",
    siteName: "EXAMPLE",
    url: "https://EXAMPLE.com/",
    title: {
      template: " %s - EXAMPLE",
      default: "EXAMPLE"
    },
    description: "EXAMPLE",
  },
};



I imported the code that works in next.js version 13, but it failed.

Please edit your question and add a Minimum Reproducible Example as code snippets not as screenshots

add  code snippets

What is METAIMAGE?
